# progressbar for form

Tags: javascript, jquery

As some will know on here, we are heavily into forms at the moment. So got me thinking, and I do know of various progress bars out there.

Such as: [Wits](http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php)

and jquery.progressbar itself.

What I havent seen as yet, is ...

Lets say we have a form, with 5 input fields. Any form will do.
Can we attach a score value for each input field, say 20% but that when user clicks into next field, the progreebar is animated, or fills up ( so progresses to 20% etc. )

This isnt quite how we want to do it, but is near enough.

Anyhoo, I am not after someone to write this, just to explain. How we attach a variable ( value ) to an input element, which then gets parsed to the progressbar.

Thats the bit I am stuck on, most of the scripts online are based on SUBMIT. And paginate a form into 5 elements, each element worth x%

Anyways Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this you mean?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateProgress(element) {
    var weight = element.attributes.weight;
    //some maths to shift the bar along by 25%
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" weight="25" onBlur="updateProgress(this);"/>
<div id="progressBar></div>
```

Comment: ahhh now that looks interesting, I reckon it might just work Cap'n Thanks Dai, will give it a whirl

Comment: I'm trying to knock up a JS fiddle example but my JS-fu is not too good I'm afraid, I mostly use it for form validation.

Comment: Well, here you go, it isn't pretty but I think its what you wanted http://www.jsfiddle.net/vNCGh/

Comment: Dai that is awesome, mate respect. Thankyou, exactly what we are trying to do, many thanks for assisting. Ste

Comment: Currently updating this now, is there a way, to align the text outside of the progress bar? say to the left hand side ??

Comment: fiddle with the CSS I suppose, I don't know much at all about layout and stuff, I code PHP for a living, hehe.